# Trying to embed an updating chart into google sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, charts, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am trying to embed a chart that updates daily, from this website:
https://alternative.me/crypto/fear-and-greed-index/
into a google sheets document.

I have tried all the commands I could come up with but to no luck. could anyone please point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed html objects into Google Sheets.
This site allows you to insert image, so you can do:

```
=image("https://alternative.me/crypto/fear-and-greed-index.png")
```

Is this what you were looking for?